# Error when trying to upload video on dailymotion with Graph API

Tags: php, api, curl, video-processing, dailymotion-api

I am trying to upload video on dailymotion using graph API here:

http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/graph-api.html

Authenticated successfully with read and write permission but when trying to upload video using below api publishing method: http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/graph-api.html#publishing Getting Errors

> stdClass Object ( [error] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 400 [message]
>   => The `url' parameter returns an invalid content type: text/plain, must be video/* [type] => invalid_parameter ) )

I am posting request to API using below cURL:

```
$fields = '';
   $data = array(
       "access_token" => $token,
       "url" => "https://www.somesite.com/demo/dailymotion/X.mp4"
    );
   $url = "https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos";
   foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
      $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
   }
   rtrim($fields, '&');

   $post = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

   $result = curl_exec($post);

   curl_close($post);
   print_r(json_decode($result));
```

Some one please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with the url to your video, it looks like it's not recognized as a video:

```
invalid content type: text/plain, must be video/* [type]
```

You should use an upload url delivered through the api: perform an HTTP GET to /file/upload to get the upload URL and post your video to this address using multipart/form-data content-type with the video in the file field. When testing your code with this url, it worked.

I have two comments though: why don't you use the php sdk ? It will make everything a lot easier for you ! Also, in order for your video to be published, you should specify a title and a channel for it, and set "published" to true, in your data array:

```
$data = array(
   "access_token" => $token,
   "channel" => "news",
   "title" => "my title",
   "published"=> True,
   "url" => $videourl
);
```

This is described at : http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/getting-started.html#publishing-videos
and you can find a use case using php sdk at http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/use-cases.html